# MySQL Return JSON array index based on property value

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table with JSON data like this:

```
{"a": [{"color": "blue", "value": 15}, {"color": "red", "value": 30}]}
```

I need to get the "value" that is inside the same object of "blue".

I thought to use the code below:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, '$.a[0].value');
```

The problem is that the "blue" object can be in any index of the array.

So, is there a way to retrieve the index first and then i'll query using the right index?

**UPDATE**

The Barmar's answer works but it needs to wrap in JSON_UNQUOTE()

Comment: Could you post the full solution with markup and everything?

Answer (score 10):

Use `JSON_SEARCH()` to find the path to `blue`.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, JSON_UNQUOTE(REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(my_data, 'one', 'blue'), '.color', '.value')))
```

`JSON_SEARCH` will return a string like `$.a[0].color`. `REPLACE` changes that to `$.a[0].value`, then you extract that element.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGYHWo5k3Ztnpi2rNhVkRt/0)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Did you test it? Because i'm receiving "Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1.". But i'll try to work it around with your explanation

Comment: No, I don't have a version of MySQL with JSON support.

Comment: It seems like the JSON path has to be a literal, you can't use an expression that calculates the path.

Comment: Just another reason to avoid using JSON in MySQL. It denormalizes your schema, and the functions are really cumbersome and limited.

Comment: Your solution works because it is returning the right path indeed. But, like you said, the MySQL is not accepting the expression. Don't know yet how to bypass that

Comment: I've been searching for sites that address it. But I haven't found anything in the documentation that confirms what we're seeing, or any discussion of it in blogs or other Q/A sites.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0.4 or newer, I think [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) may be useful. I haven't looked at it carefully to see how to use it for this.

Comment: Your answer was usefull and it worked wraping the sentence in JSON_UNQUOTE()

Comment: Excellent workaround, props to @Barmar, helped me a lot and saved me plenty of time, cheers!

Comment: I'm trying to run the following snippet, but it doesn't work: `SET @k = '[{"color": "blue", "value": 15}, {"color": "red", "value": 30}]';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@k, JSON_REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(@k, 'one', 'blue'), '.color', '.value'));` any idea?
I'm using MySQL 5.7.12

Comment: `JSON_REPLACE` should be `REPLACE`

Comment: Still error: `Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1.`

Comment: This should work:
`SET @k = '[{"color": "blue", "value": 15}, {"color": "red", "value": 30}]';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@k, JSON_UNQUOTE(REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(@k, 'one', 'blue'), '.color', '.value')));`

Comment: I just figured that out myself, and updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that! thank you so much for your help!! there aren't any good example for a case like this!

Comment: You didn't see it because you wrote your comment before I edited.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of using [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

```
select j.* from d, json_table(d.data, '$.a[*]' columns (
  color varchar(20) path '$.color', 
  value int path '$.value')
) as j;
+-------+-------+
| color | value |
+-------+-------+
| blue  |    15 |
| red   |    30 |
+-------+-------+
```

You can then apply conditions in the `WHERE` clause, as if you had stored the data in a normal table.

```
select j.* from d, json_table(d.data, '$.a[*]' columns (
  color varchar(20) path '$.color', 
  value int path '$.value')
) as j 
where j.color = 'blue';
+-------+-------+
| color | value |
+-------+-------+
| blue  |    15 |
+-------+-------+
```

This requires you to write a complex query like this EVERY TIME you query the JSON data.

One wonders if it would have been easier to store the JSON in a normal table from the start.

I often recommend to MySQL users that storing data as JSON makes more work for you, if you need to make SQL expressions to reference individual fields within the JSON. I wouldn't use JSON in these cases, I'd explode the JSON array into rows, and the JSON fields into columns of a set of normal tables. Then you can write simpler queries, you can optimize with indexes, and you can use constraints and data types properly.

JSON is the most easily misused feature of the recent MySQL releases.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of the usefulness of the JSON datatype. Theoretically it probably seemed like a good idea, but in practice it seems like a nightmare (not speaking from personal experience, just from trying to answer questions on SO).

Comment: JSON was implemented to satisfy market demand. MongoDB has it, PostgreSQL has it, [even Informix has a BSON data type](https://ifmx.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/working-with-json-data-from-sql/).

Developers keep demanding "flexibility" to pour unstructured data into their database, because they can't define a concrete schema. Often it isn't their fault either, because they're working on a product specification that won't commit to enough concrete detail from which to define a schema.

Comment: Yeah, I understand why compromises like this happen. Well, it's better than something I saw in the Invision Power Board source code several years ago -- they store some options in PHP `serialize()` format, and use `LIKE` or `RLIKE` to search for matches.

Comment: Ouch. That sounds like a classic example of the [problem with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).