# In MYSQL, is it possible to SELECT something that will be defined in the WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a system which contains items that may each belong to more than one parent. I need to be able to retrieve all of an item's children, and it's children's children.. ad nauseam. OK well there are 5 levels.

Each item has (or should have) a json column named "belongs_to_json" (also more columns such as "id" and whatnot) which contains each parent, order combination. e.g. [{"parent": 2, "order": 4},{"parent": 13, "order": 1}]

I can search for this and others with the same parent by combining PHP and MYSQL (idea found on stackoverflow previously)

First I run a query (codeigniter framework) getting some item parents and put the query in a $qry_classes variable.

```
    $sql_classes = "SELECT t.id 
    FROM table t 
    WHERE JSON_SEARCH(t.belongs_to_json, 'all', '2') LIKE '%.parent%';";
    $qry_classes = $this->db->query($sql_classes);
```

Then I use the results from that query to write a new WHERE statement.

```
    $s_rewrite_array = array_map(function($row) {
    return "JSON_SEARCH(t.belongs_to_json, 'all', '{$row->id}') LIKE '%.parent%'";
    }, $qry_classes->return_array() );
    $sections_condition = implode(" OR ", $s_rewrite_array);
    $sql_sections = "
        SELECT  t.id
        FROM    table t
        WHERE   ($sections_condition)
    ";
    $qry_sections = $this->db->query($sql_sections);
```

The problem comes when I have an item with multiple parents and I want to return the parent that was used in the WHERE clause in the SELECT clause.

Something like

```
    SELECT t.*, non_existant_column FROM table t WHERE 
    JSON_SEARCH(t.belongs_to_json, 'all', '{$row->id}' as non_existant_column) LIKE '%.parent%;
```

obviously not a real thing but I'm hoping there is an equivalent. Or maybe different way to solve the issue.

Comment: I wish people would stop trying to use the JSON type. It just makes things harder.

Comment: Would you suggest a different method for holding a parent,order combination in one column?

Comment: Use a table with `parent` and `order` columns.

Comment: And what if the number of parent/order pairs was indeterminate?

Comment: Each pair is in its own row.

Comment: `SELECT parent, order WHERE parent = $row->id`

Comment: Oh, so do you mean that you would create another table with columns id, parent, order and just add another row for each new pair? Because that would be simple and would definitely make me feel pretty stupid that I didn't think about that to begin with.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for helping me see things from a better angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use put a literal in the `SELECT` list, you don't need to get it from the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT t.*, '{$row->id}' AS parent 
FROM table t 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(t.belongs_to_json, 'all', '{$row->id}') LIKE '%.parent%;
```

If you're using MySQL 8.0, you can probably use `JSON_TABLE` to find `parent: 2` instead of your method. See [MySQL Return JSON array index based on property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193438/mysql-return-json-array-index-based-on-property-value/56315064#56315064)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried that actually and the issue is that I have to make a different SELECT statement for each one and then UNION each one together.

Comment: Also, unfortunately I don't have the option to upgrade to mysql 8.x at the moment, 5.7 is my only option.

Comment: Normalize your schema so you can use normal relational queries.

Comment: So the solution for me was discovered in the comments attached to the question but I'm marking this as the correct answer because really, I should be using a different table to denote parentage, not JSON. Thanks!