# MySQL: Update specific values in JSON array of objects

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I'm using MySQL 5.7.12, and have a `JSON` column with the following data:

`[{"tpe": "I", "val": 1}, {"tpe": "C", "val": 2}, {"tpe": "A", "val": 3}]`

I would like to UPDATE `val` from 2 into 20 WHERE `tpe`='C'.

Here is my attempt:

`UPDATE user SET data = JSON_SET(data->"$[1]", '$.val', 20);`

This does update the value but it trims the other elements in the array and it becomes only a json-object, here how it looks after the update:

`{"tpe": "C", "val": 20}`

How can I get this right?

2nd question: is there a way to dynamically get the json object in the array so I don't have to hard code `"$[1]"` ? I tried to use `JSON_SEARCH` ??

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Your second question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193438/mysql-return-json-array-index-based-on-property-value/56315064#56315064

Comment: Problems like this are why putting JSON into SQL tables is a horrible idea. Normalize your tables and it becomes trivial.