# How can I remove an element from a JSON array using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, json-extract, json-remove, json-search

I have a table with JSON data like this:

```json
{"entries": [{"color": "blue", "value": 15, "name": "john"}, {"color": "red", "value": 30, "name": "doe"}]}
```

I need to remove the object in the array that has value x.

The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT data_source, JSON_EXTRACT('$.entries[*].value')
```

Which allows me to see all the values in an array.

I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT JSON_REMOVE(data_source, '$.entries[*].use_id') = x
```

How can I create a JSON path that would allow me to find the value? And then remove that object it's in?

Comment: I know it's similar to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193438/mysql-return-json-array-index-based-on-property-value

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(...) AS extracted WHERE extracted=?`